# Retrieving username and details form SAMLResponse

Tags: spring-saml

I am using ssocircle as my IDP.
How to get the user name in response any code example will help.
my saml request as below.

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                     AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:38080/ICDWeb/saml/SSO"
                     Destination="https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/ssocircle"
                     ForceAuthn="false"
                     ID="a3h6ehei2fjhghi3240a10e2ad03ifj"
                     IsPassive="false"
                     IssueInstant="2015-03-27T06:12:49.597Z"
                     ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                     Version="2.0"
                     >
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://172.16.246.146:38080:ICDWeb/saml/metadata</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

Comment: I am getting mail Id  as principal but I need  User name

Comment: What did you have to do to get SSO Circle to send you the username as the principal?

Comment: While uploading the SP metadata you can check the checkbox against user id checkbox which you can find ssocircle metadata upload page. This will sent you the username in the assertion in saml response in th user id attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to configure your IDP to send attributes you require.

On SP side you can load attributes sent by IDP from the `SAMLCredential` object which is available in `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials()`. Call to e.g. `credential.getAttributeAsString("myAttribute")` will return the value sent by IDP. The `NameID` value sent by IDP is available as principal in `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`.